# Take values from input text area and place them in a <div>

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

#### HTML code

```
<form novalidate>
  <div class="list">
    <div class="list list-inset">
      <label class="item item-input" id="descriptions">
        <input type="text" height: "90" class="description" placeholder="Description ..." ng-model="describe">
      </label>
      <label input="email" class="item item-input" id="email" ng-model="email">
        <span class="input-label">Email</span>
        <input type="email">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input" ng-model="date">
        <span class="input-label">Date</span>
        <input type="date">
      </label>
    </div>
    <button class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-click="insertData(describe,email, date); AddItem()">Add Task</button>

    <button class="button button-block button-assertive" ng-click="closeModal()">cancel</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I want to have a function that takes the values of these input text fields and passes them in a `<div>` when the *Add Task* button is clicked.

Comment: They are inputs, not textareas.

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to set up a click event handler for the button that copies the data. See comments inline below:

```js
// Get references to DOM elements needed to solve problem:
var addTask = document.querySelector(".button-balanced");
var description = document.querySelector(".description");
var email = document.querySelector("[type=email]");
var date = document.querySelector("[type=date]");

// Set up click event handling function for button
addTask.addEventListener("click", function(){
  
  // Create an new "row" for data
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  
  // populate the "row" with the values from the text fields
  div.textContent = description.value + ", " + date.value + ", " + email.value;
  
  // Add the row to the document
  document.body.appendChild(div);
});
```

```html
<form novalidate>
  <div class="list">
    <div class="list list-inset">
      <label class="item item-input" id="descriptions">
        <input type="text" height: "90" class="description" placeholder="Description ..." ng-model="describe">
      </label>
      <label input="email" class="item item-input" id="email" ng-model="email">
        <span class="input-label">Email</span>
        <input type="email">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input" ng-model="date">
        <span class="input-label">Date</span>
        <input type="date">
      </label>
    </div>
    <button class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-click="insertData(describe,email, date); AddItem()">Add Task</button>

    <button class="button button-block button-assertive" ng-click="closeModal()">cancel</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: anyway to do this with angularjs?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is the duplication of IDs:

```
<label id="email">
  <input id="email">
</label>
```

That is invalid code as IDs have to be unique within the same document.
If you access the content of the `<input>` you will get undefined if you use the ID to access the element as the ID is taken by the label already.

Labels are associated using the `for` attribute:

```
<label for="email">
  <input id="email">
</label>
```

This might fix it.

In case it does not, you can use plain JavaScript and the DOM:

```
<label for="email">Email: <input id="email"></label>
<label for="date">Date: <input id="date" type="date"></label>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<script>
  document.getElementById("add").addEventListener('click', function() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.textContent = document.getElementById('email').value + ' on the ' + document.getElementById('date').value;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: How is your answer different from mine?

Comment: 1. I haven't seen yours while I drafted
2. I point out the ID collision in the original code
3. I did not leave the angular specific bits in the HTML